# Jsoup - <noscript> content in <head> gets interpreted as text

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I came up with a problem that parsing the following HTML results into unwanted result.

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jsoup</title>
<noscript><p>thisisatest</p></noscript>
<noscript><img id="tracking-test-noscript" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" src="http://fullwithsheep/img/tracking3.jpg"></noscript>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><p>thisisatest</p></noscript>
<p>This is <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a>.</p>
<noscript><img id="tracking-test-noscript" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" src="http://fullwithsheep/img/tracking3.jpg"></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

JSOUP interpretation of the Document

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jsoup</title>
<noscript>&lt;p&gt;thisisatest</noscript>
<noscript>&lt;img  id="tracking-test-noscript" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" src="http://fullwithsheep/img/tracking3.jpg"&gt;</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><p>thisisatest</p></noscript>
<p>This is <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a>.</p>
<noscript><img id="tracking-test-noscript" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" src="http://fullwithsheep/img/tracking3.jpg"></noscript>
</body></html>
```

[image]

As you can see the innerHTML from the noscript tags within head node where interpreted as text - what I want is that jsoup still will interpret them as html instead of text (without sanitizing < into `&lt;` and so on)

What I did as a fix to this problem as a workaround is selecting all noscript tags after interrupting Jsoup.parse and try to transform the text of the respective noscript tag back to html. However, this feels like it is not the right way to do it - Is this a bug within Jsoup Library or is this behaviour intentioned?

Comment: If you like the answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xmlParser` to avoid undesired HTML modifications:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Default parser `treats input as HTML5, and enforces the creation of a normalised document, based on a knowledge of the semantics of the incoming tags`
while xmlParser `assumes no knowledge of the incoming tags and does not treat it as HTML, rather creates a simple tree directly from the input` and that's what you need.

Quotes come from the documentation: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser()

Comment: Any idea why the same code gets interpreted diffrent in head and in the body?
this line in particular: <noscript><p>thisisatest</p></noscript>